# Python Extraction of English terms and French terms separately in xml file (IATE database export)

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I have a tbx file which is a terminology database extract in xml format. Here is an example :

```
 <termEntry id="IATE-47204">
    <descripGrp>
      <descrip type="subjectField">2431, 52</descrip>
    </descripGrp>
    <langSet xml:lang="en">
      <tig>
        <term>insurance company</term>
        <termNote type="termType">fullForm</termNote>
        <descrip type="reliabilityCode">3</descrip>
      </tig>
    </langSet>
    <langSet xml:lang="fr">
      <tig>
        <term>compagnie d'assurance</term>
        <termNote type="termType">fullForm</termNote>
        <descrip type="reliabilityCode">3</descrip>
      </tig>
    </langSet>
  </termEntry>
```

I have tried many codes but no success because I cannot figure out how to select specific terms under grandparent nodes with language attributes. In all my codes, the command selected all term nodes (both in English and in French). For instance I would like to extract the term insurance company, copy it in a text file and extract compagnie d'assurance and copy it in a different text file.

This code did not work:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
root = tree.parse("export_EN_FR_essai IATE - Copie.xml")
for node in root.findall(".//langSet[@lang='en']/tig"):
    for type in node.getchildren():
        print(type.text)
```

This code almost worked (I can't find the correct command line after if a == 'en' to print or copy only the English term):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse('export_EN_FR_essai IATE - Copie.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('langSet')
print(len(itemlist))
for s in itemlist:
    a = (s.attributes['xml:lang'].value)
    if a == 'en':
        print ("anglais")
        print (s)
        for terme in root.xpath('//langSet[@xml:lang = "en"]/tig/term/'):
            print (terme.text)
    if a == 'fr':
        print ("français")
```

Comment: Add a minimum XML example including XML declaration with namespaces since `xml:lang` belongs to a known namespace. Xpath will not work if namespaces are not used.

Comment: I am not sure about how to declare this but I have found this address: http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace:lang. Perhaps these lines could be added then:
namespaces = {'lang': 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespacel#'}
root.findall('lang:Class', namespaces)

Comment: Or to facilitate the extraction process, another option could be to use "lang" standard attribute. I could easily make a search and replace xml:lang with "lang".

Comment: does the XML have those namespaces declared? Add them verbatim.

Comment: Hello Luis! Thanks for your input. I have not declared the namespace because I was able to resolve the issue by searching and replacing the attribute with an autonomous one (such as "lang"). I will publish the code lines I have done (very easy and very basic when without the xml:lang attribute). thks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by replacing the namespace attributes with regular attributes. After that, the basic code allowed me to find separately the English and French terms. See below:

```
print ("Les termes anglais :")
    for terme in tree.xpath('/termEntry/langSet[@lang="en"]/tig/term'):
    print (terme.text)

print ("Les termes français :")
     for terme in tree.xpath('/termEntry/langSet[@lang="fr"]/tig/term'):
     print (terme.text)
```